# Image does not translate when keys are pressed

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Want to move an image across the screen. At the moment the image renders but does not translate the page when the specific keys are pressed. Can't see to get it to work - any suggestions?? I included the entire block of code as I believe it makes more sense.

```
var player;
var img;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage("charcter.png");
}

function setup() {
  background(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  createCanvas(1000, 600);
  player = new Astro(0,0);
}

function draw() {
   // clear();
    player.show();
    player.update();
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    player.dir(0, -10);
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    player.dir(0, 10);
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    player.dir(10, 0);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    player.dir(-10, 0);
  }
}

function Astro(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
    this.img = img;
    this.show = function() {
        image(img, this.x, this.y);
    };

    this.update = function() {

          this.x += this.xSpeed;
          this.y += this.ySpeed;

        if (this.x > width || this.x < 0) {
            this.xSpeed = this.xSpeed * -1;
        }
        if (this.y > height || this.y < 0) {
            this.ySpeed = this.ySpeed * -1;
        }

    };
    this.dir = function(x, y) {
      this.xspeed = x;
      this.yspeed = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please press `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: shouldn't you be adding this.xSpeed to this.x and this.ySpeed to this.y in some function? That's how the image will move. Also, in the this.dir() function, the position you wish to move your image to should be added to the this.x and this.y respectively

Comment: Sorry just added that in - still doesn;t move

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a step back and [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). For example, are you sure the `keyPressed()` function is firing? Are you sure the `if` statements are working the way you expected? Are you sure the `player.dir()` function is being called?

Use `console.log()` statements, or use the JavaScript debugger, to answer all of the above. Figure out exactly which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected, and then isolate that problem in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (For example, don't include image loading code if the problem is not directly related to loading images. Use a basic rectangle instead.) Good luck.